# Should a suggested edit that adds clarification be accepted?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I recently stumbled across [this suggested edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/126596) in the *Suggested edits* review queue.

It took some thought as usually, I would just reject the edit immediately for this reason after reading what was changed:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

But then I saw this at the top:

> Comment: I'm the original poster but am unable to login to make edits. I have clarified in order to address questions raised in answers/comments.

It took a few minutes to think about what to do, then I decided to reject it still. The OP could use the *forgot password* screen to recover their account, I didn't know exactly why they couldn't log in.

I then posted [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52272268#52272268) in the *You Are Here* chat asking why a reviewer approved this edit, whether they made a mistake or it was an oversight on my part.

The reviewer then posted [this reply](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52272494#52272494):

> As a new user they wouldn't be able to reply as a comment until they earn some rep, (I thought, as it's no longer their post) which most new users wont understand. I've not come across this situation much as usually they reply in an answer which gets deleted and edited in
> Is there an official way to do this, like reject and edit it in ourselves?

That got me thinking, what is the official way to do this?

I saw the user posted this (deleted) answer on their post:

> Edit: I have edited this post considerably and asked it be deleted as the reason for posting it is also gone. I was trying to reply to HankyPanky on an important point, but they have edited out the very point I was replying to.
>
> Not editing this part out though: I am the person that posted the question. I am sure I am violating SE rules by answering my own question, but I need to clarify something. SE is having a technical problem that is preventing me from confirming my account with the email I used to post the question so I cant edit it, and I dont have 50 reputation to just comment.

**Now, I agree the post should stay even if the reason for posting is gone as they already answered *no*. I then edited the information from the edit in.**

Since we now know there is a technical problem, I would’ve approved this is I saw this answer at the time of review.

**Is there any guidance we can agree on as in what to do in this situation in the future?**

Comment: In a case like this, I'd advise flagging and letting a moderator take a look. They can check the IP's of both users to make sure that they are indeed the same person.

Comment: @scohe001 That's what I always do, reject (usually with a custom reason) and flag and ask for a mod to take a look. Note though that I've had one declined recently for this but that's because of recent events it took over 2 weeks to handle and had become obsolete since (at least that's the only sensible reason for declining it I can see).

Comment: Related (but too old): [Comment Smuggling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77781/282094), also [OP uses edit to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109259/282094), ***and*** *same* question as yours (but [for *answers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234038/282094)).